# Does someone have a valid example on CAS Proxy Granting Ticket?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, cas

I need to implement a CAS Proxy Granting Ticket System.

So I need to understand the system. There is a good doc [here](http://www.ja-sig.org/wiki/display/CAS/Proxy+CAS+Walkthrough), but I have no idea about the proxyCallback  I need.

Could someone explain me that ?

Comment: I had implemented CAS SSO successfully so maybe I can help you, but you have to explain your doubts a little more clear.

Comment: I followed the article at http://www.ja-sig.org/wiki/display/CAS/Proxy+CAS+Walkthrough but I don't know which Url I need for the pgtUrl parameter et "Step Two (b): verify the ticket and enable further proxying". 
I don't understand the role of the pgtUrl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CAS will invoke the pgtURL to provide a special ticket that will enable that application to acquire new tickets for other applications.
This is the setup in **web.xml**:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>casproxy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>edu.yale.its.tp.cas.proxy.ProxyTicketReceptor</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>casproxy</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/casProxy/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

To get a new ticket for another service with the special ticket:

```
SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
CasAuthenticationToken auth = (CasAuthenticationToken)sc.getAuthentication();
String pgtIOU = auth.getProxyGrantingTicketIou();
String newTicket = ProxyTicketReceptor.getProxyTicket(pgtIOU, anotherService);
```

Then you redirect to that service giving to it the new ticket.

Comment: Okay.
I didn't noticed that I had to change web.xml.
I'm not a Java guru. Are you meaning I have write some java code to enable proxy Granting ticket ?

Comment: You only need to code the part that use the PGT to obtain new tickets for other applications. The part that is in charge of receiving the PGT and store it for you to use it, is already coded in the ProxyTicketReceptor servlet.